# Failed to authenticate to the freeradius server with added user

Tags: freeradius

I was trying to test my freeRadius server in debug mode after building the source code on my Ubuntu VM.
I also use this official tutorial as the reference: https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/basic-configuration-howto

**My goal is:**

Add a new user "testing", whose password is "password", to the freeradius config and successfully authenticate to the freeradius server as user "testing".

**Below are the steps I have tried:**

(1) I added the user info to the top line of "/usr/local/etc/raddb/users"

```
testing Cleartext-Password := "password"
```

I didn't make changes to "sudo nano /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf"

(2) I started freeradius server in debug mode

```
sudo radiusd -X
```

and the server shows `Ready to process requests`

(3) I open a new terminal and tried to send the request with new user's info

```
radtest testing password localhost 0 testing123
```

**The actual result is: Access-Reject**

On the client side:

```
Sent Access-Request Id 128 from 0.0.0.0:41704 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
    User-Name = "testing"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "password"
Received Access-Reject Id 128 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:41704 length 20
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

On the server side:

```sh
(1) Received Access-Request Id 128 from 127.0.0.1:41704 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
(1)   User-Name = "testing"
(1)   User-Password = "password"
(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
(1)   NAS-Port = 0
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0xaf245c154458b4236bcca590799eeef4
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)   authorize {
(1)     policy filter_username {
(1)       if (&User-Name) {
(1)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(1)       if (&User-Name)  {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> TRUE
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  {
(1)           update request {
(1)             &Module-Failure-Message += 'Rejected: User-Name contains multiple ..s'
(1)           } # update request = noop
(1)           [reject] = reject
(1)         } # if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  = reject
(1)       } # if (&User-Name)  = reject
(1)     } # policy filter_username = reject
(1)   } # authorize = reject
(1) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(1) # Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(1) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(1) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> testing
(1) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(1)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(1)     [eap] = noop
(1)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(1)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(1)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(1)       else {
(1)         [noop] = noop
(1)       } # else = noop
(1)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(1)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(1) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
(1) Sending delayed response
(1) Sent Access-Reject Id 128 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:41704 length 20
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 128 with timestamp +112
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that previously I messed up with the building process. I used `make deb' to build the package and then switch back to build from the source code. After a few hours and debug, now I finally get the expected output.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the process in troubleshooting on your own issues? It might help others like me who may facing this similar problems in the future. Thanks.